# Buttondownfcn doesn't work on slider

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm making a simple real time data viewer with buttons like play, pause and slider using MATLAB GUI.
After the user presses play slider needs to be updated every step (50 samples per second). That functionality is interfering with manually moving slider (you'd have to move it in 1/50th of the second).
For now I've set updating of the slider every 50th time (so once every second) and it works fine, unless you hold the slider longer then it takes to update.

The problem is that if slider property Enable is on, Buttondownfcn doesn't work for left click (it does for right one). Using Buttondownfcn I would be able to lock the updating and solve the problem completely. Is there any way around this?

```
% --- Executes on slider movement.
function slider_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
disp('Slider movement')

% --- Executes on button down.
function slider_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
disp('Button down')
```

Comment: could you show some minimal example code?

Comment: If you want to simulate this behavior just start MATLAB GUI and add a slider. Add Callback and ButtonDownFcn as callbacks and add some printed messages like I did using disp. Then just switch between property Enable (on/off) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve interrupt play by setting the `Enable` property of your slider to `off` or `inactive` when you press your play button and using a `ButtonDownFcn` function that stops play and sets `Enable` back to `on`.

Using a `togglebutton` as my play button (other control widgets should work as long as you can save a boolean flag somewhere accessible), I used the following as `Callback` for the button:

```
function playcallback(toggle_button, ~, slider_)
set(slider_, 'Enable', 'inactive'); %slider is disabled
while get(toggle_button, 'Value') %Value is used as flag for playing
    current_value = get(slider_, 'Value');
    set(slider_, 'Value', rem(current_value + 0.01, 1)); %shift slider (looping)
    pause(1/50);
end
set(slider_, 'Enable', 'on'); %done playing, turn slider back on
end
```

And the following as `ButtonDownFcn` for the slider:

```
function stopslide(~, ~, toggle_button)
%play flag off: in playcallback, the while loop stops,
%the slider is enabled and the playcallback function returns
set(toggle_button, 'Value', 0); 
end
```

You can register these callbacks like this:

```
set(toggle_button_handle, 'Callback', {@playcallback, slider_handle});
set(slider_handle, 'ButtonDownFcn', {@stopslide, toggle_button_handle});
```

Caveat: if you start adding other widgets interacting with the slider/play button in a similar manner to this, you increase your chance of introducing race conditions.

Comment: I know I can do that but then you wouldn't be able to change time while the data is being reproduced and that is not very user friendly :)

Comment: Ok. I think I don't entirely understand how you use the slider in your GUI. Have you got an example application you want to emulate to show? So far I understand it the following way: you get data from an external source (50 times per second); you keep a buffer of data for N samples; the slider is used to pick which sample to display; the display will always update every 1/50 of a second, unless paused.